# Android WebView: click tel: in HTML results in "Webpage not available"

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView loading an URL with pure HTML. when I click the "tel:" URI, it shows "Webpage not available". I googled a lot and found a lot in stackoverflow.com, but all of them is to call shouldOverrideUrlLoading, but none of them is my solution, please see below for more details.

1. the HTML from "http://testurl/test1/test2/":
   < !DOCTYPE html>< html >< body >< a href='tel:1234567890' >1234567890< / a>< / body>< / html>
2. code sample:

see comment...

when I click the "1234567890" text in `WebView`, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not called, and in the same `WebView` it shows "webpage not available".

I'm running on android 4.4.2, which introduces a WebKit `WebView`, which behaves differently than 4.3 and earlier versions. refer to: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs

what can I do to handle such "tel:" click in 4.4 WebView?

Comment: mAboutPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.about_page);
mAboutPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mAboutPage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClick(this));
mAboutPage.loadUrl("http://testurl/test1/test2/");

Comment: private final static class WebViewClientClick extends WebViewClient {
 private Context context;
 private WebViewClientClick(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (-1 != url.indexOf("tel:")) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
   context.startActivity(intent);
  } else {
   view.loadUrl(url);
  }
  return true;
 }
}

Comment: i add in html another href: <a href="testdir/testdir1">test text</a>. when i click "test text", "http://myserver/testdir/testdir1" is opened just within the webview, but not called shouldOverrideUrlLoading()...

Comment: Please edit your own question rather than adding comments.